# (Answered: A Persian Tar) What is the name of this stringed instrument? It is stringed, skinny, and has a hour-glass-shaped-body

Tags: instruments, string-instruments

[image]

What is the name of this stringed instrument?

If any are curious as to where I got this image from, it is here:

Comment: It's stated in the video's description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a Persian [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(string_instrument)) to me.

Comment: What reasoning was used for this to be construed as an unacceptable answer. Short, true, nevertheless correct.

Comment: Tim - looks like an auto flag based on length